# Accessing data from calling function: logging original source of function call

Tags: python, logging, introspection, sanic

I have a web-application that I want to add logging to (but I feel this is more generally applicable). Most HTTP-requests don't need logging, but some actions cause external calls to be generated, and these should be logged.

A single incoming HTTP request can launch off 0 or more backend requests, and I'd like to log the source of these backend-requests so they can be traced back to the original call.

My naive approach is to add a "client id" to the whole call chain, like this:

```
def do_something_log_worthy(client_id, parameters):
    logger.info("{source}: caused something to be done".format(client_id))
    # something

def generic_intermediate_func_1(client_id, parameters):
    if unusual_case(parameters):
        do_something_log_worthy(client_id, parameters)

# ... some more levels generic wrappers

def http_request(client_id, request):
    # Here I get the actual client ID
    generic_intermediate_func_N(client_id, "foo", "bar")
```

While this works, I would like to avoid adding `client_id` throughout the full call chain. Since most of the functions/methods have nothing to do with the client-logic, it feels wrong to add a pass-through parameter there.

The alternative approach would be to use a global variable to hold "the most recent client", but globals are almost always a bad choice, especially when using multi-threaded and/or async code (which I am using).

Is there a pythonic way to solve this problem? Ideally, I'd like something like

```
logger.info("{source}: foobar".format(
    call_stack.nearest_frame_decorated_with(some_decorater).get_variable_value("client_id")
))  # all entry-points are decorated with @app.route('/path/to/foo')
```

but that feels like accessing "private" data. Is there a way to accomplish this in a clean way?

In case it helps: The web-app is written in [Sanic](https://www.fullstackpython.com/sanic.html), an asyncio-based web framework. Logging is done with the standard python logger facility.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be exactly what you need, but from a previous job I remember middleware adding a request uuid and response uuid to logs on api calls.

You could write middleware that adds a unique id to your request in the beginning of the chain, then pass the request through, much like sanic does with routing to endpoint functions/methods.

Ex of what I remember the elasticsearch logs used to looks like:

requests-2018-01-01 node

```
    {
"timestamp": "Sun Jan 01 16:13:39 SAST 2018",
"payload": "{'user_id':'abcdef', 'action': 'calculate_balance'}
"request_id": "03cfd743661f07975fa2f1220c5194cbaff48451",
"status": 500
}
```

response-2018-01-01

```
{
"timestamp": "Sun Jan 01 16:13:39 SAST 2018",
"message": "Internal Server Error"
"request_id": "03cfd743661f07975fa2f1220c5194cbaff48451",
"response_id": "3330b4373640f9e4604991e73c7e86bfd8da2dc3",
"status": 500
}
```

It made looking through the logs easy cause you could search by request id in internal-logs, request-logs, response-logs, etc.

Hope that helps?